# Is it safe to run a lot of UNION ALL in one query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I received query from analytic to automate and it contains about 10-15 UNION and UNION ALL commands. Each subquery contains several joins of big tables.

I think it will be more safe and optimal way to save results of subqueries into temp tables and union them.

So how UNION(ALL) works on deep level? Is my way better for optimisation?

Comment: safe _or_ optimization?

Comment: May be you should consider adding few "views" on your database and simplify your query?

Comment: Consider this - SQL is a declarative language. You tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. If you can apply an unthinking mechanical transformation on your query that improves performance, what makes you think the query optimizer is incapable of performing the same transformation?

Comment: If you have to have a query like this, it almost sounds like you have a design flaw; especially if all the tables have the same columns, rather than different ones that you're amalgamating.

Comment: You should test it on your hardware and software, measure resource consumption and execution time, decide what is more important for you and then choose the option on that criteria. DMBS is quite intelligent and *IS* suited for data processing.

Comment: One more point that should be considered is the purpose of this query. You have written "automate", so will the data it produces be loaded to somewhere? If yes, then the query can be splitted into separate subqueries and each can be executed separately (maybe in parallel with appropriate partitioning of target table). This scenario is reasonable for DW, for example. This way you can improve performance of the overall process and recalculate only one part in case of some failure, but in such scenario temp tables are also can be excluded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "safe", but *a priori* there is no reason to split the query into separate tables -- unless you want to query those tables independently.

Splitting the results into separate tables has some big downsides -- namely, managing the extra tables you make.  I have memories of nightmares tracking down errors because some intermediate table was not updated correctly.

In a `UNION ALL`, the subqueries are really isolated from each other.  There is no reason to split the queries into tables to make the overall query more performant.

Introducing intermediate tables introduces complexity, so you need a good reason for that.  There are good reasons.  For instance, if the view is used many times and the subqueries are expensive, then materializing them makes the query more efficient.  In fact, you might find that indexed views (SQL Server's approach to materialized views) are a handy way of doing this.  Materialized views (whatever they are called) get around the issue of out-of-date intermediate tables.

Comment: I have split the request into several tables -- no significant difference, indeed. Actually, it was even slightly slower. I think it might be tricky to deal with such a long query and that's why I felt doubts when saw it. Maybe we really have to know more about views and consider using them. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, saving each subquery into a temp table won't really help/change much from a memory consumption point of view.  If you run the full query with so many unions, SQL Server will consume server memory to hold the temporary results, before delivering the final result set.  Temp tables also get stored in server memory, which means the memory footprint would be about the same.

For a quick comment on `UNION` versus `UNION ALL`, if you can logically accept the latter instead of the former, then it might help performance.  This is because `UNION` by itself means to aggregate results, and *also* remove duplicates.  `UNION ALL` has no such duplicate removal step, which means it generally will outperform plain `UNION`.